# Export data to CSV in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to export some data to csv and I am trying this code

```
import csv

nms = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

f = open('numbers2.csv', 'w')

with f:

    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for row in nms:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

but it returns this error:

````
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/csv.py", line 3, in <module>
    import csv
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop\csv.py", line 11, in <module>
    writer = csv.writer(f)
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer' ```
Any help???
````

Comment: You named your script "csv.py", masking the `csv` module. You are importing your own script. Just rename your script to something else.

Answer (score 1):

When a module is missing a well-defined variable, its good to ask whether you've really imported the right module. You can `print(csv.__file__)` to see whether you got the right thing.

Python has a rule that it will add a script's directory to the module search path so that it can find other modules you may be using in your project. One downside is that if you have a module with the same name as an installed module, your local module wins.

From the traceback its easy to see the problem. Your script is `File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/csv.py"`. Since you named your script "csv.py", it was imported instead of the standard module. The solution is to name your .py file something else.

Answer (score 0):

I've runned you code using python 3.8.2 and it wok's well. If you are using an old python version try to install the last version, available [here.](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

to check you python's version, type:

```
pythnon --version
```

Comment: Try naming your test file "csv.py", you'll get the same error.